# Hover effect not working from the second time in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I'm facing a weird problem with safari

I'm now developing a website that loads its contents with Ajax I'm applying this by using Hashchange methodology and when hashchange

I'm getting the url and then load the content for the page

```
    jQuery(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    url = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (!url) {           
        return;
    }

        var tsTimeStamp= new Date().getTime();

        jQuery.get(url, { action: "get", time: tsTimeStamp,"ajaxed": "true"} , function (data, status, xmlHttp) {

            var container = jQuery("#hidden");
            container.html(xmlHttp.responseText);
            var content = jQuery(".inner", container).html();}
```

and then after loading the content I'm applying some jquery stuff like

```
                var ids = " ";
                var ids_2 = " ";
                for (var i = 0; i <= jQuery(".cats").length; i++) {
                    ids += "#c" + i + ",";
                    ids_2 += "#l" + i + ",";
                }

                ids = ids.substr(0, (ids.length) - 1);
                ids_2 = ids_2.substr(0, (ids_2.length) - 1);
                jQuery(ids).hover(function () {
                    href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
                    id = jQuery('a[href="' + href + '"]').attr("id");
                    jQuery("img").not(jQuery("img."+id)).addClass("op");

                }, function () {
                    time = setTimeout(remove, 200);

                });                                     

                jQuery(ids_2).hover(function () {

                    clearTimeout(time);
                    jQuery("img.op").removeClass("op");
                    href = jQuery(this).attr("href");
                    id = jQuery('a[href="' + href + '"]').attr("id");
                    jQuery("img").not(jQuery("img." + id)).addClass("op");

                }, function () {

                    jQuery("img.op").delay(200).removeClass("op");

                });
                function remove() {
                    jQuery("img.op").removeClass("op");
                }
```

The above code is applying hover over effect on map areas for images

**(this code is applicable to 4 pages).**

All the above code is working fine with all the browser except Safari

The problem is when the first page that contains the maps loaded the code is working fine but when you load another page contains the same areas it will stop working until the whole page being refreshed.

seems like it caches the handler for the first time and then does not apply it to the new selectors

Keep in mind that when Alert ids & ids_2 it gives the correct values but when using alert inside the .hover it does not fire in the second time.

I know its complicated but really I'm stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be better to have small code snippets, but from what I can see you're having problem on binding jQuery handlers on newly created elements. To solve this problem you have to use the jQuery .live().

**From jQuery documentation:**

> This method is a variation on the
>   basic .bind() method for attaching
>   event handlers to elements. When
>   .bind() is called, the elements that
>   the jQuery object refers to get the
>   handler attached; elements that get
>   introduced later do not, so they would
>   require another .bind() call.
>
> The .live() method provides an
>   alternative to this behavior. To bind
>   a click handler to the target element
>   using this method:

```
$('.hoverme').live('hover', function(){
    // Live handler called.
});
```

> And then later add a new element:

```
$('body').append('<div class="hoverme">Another target</div>');
```

> Then clicks on the new element will
>   also trigger the handler.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I'm adding the new elements first and then I'm binding the handlers for these elements. I added the new elements first because I've to count the number of elements before binding the handlers. and it works fine in all browsers except safari and Also it runs for the first time only on safari

Comment: @Mohamed Amgad you should consider improving your question setting up a smaller example, or giving a link to a working example of this code.